# Find Second Largest Number Without Arrays

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have to make program that will return the second highest number from user input.

The user can input a **minimum** of **2** numbers and a **maximum** of **10** numbers. The user can only input integers (not decimals), to stop the program I am using 0.

**My problem is:** if I input **1,2,2,0** it outputs **2** which is **not** correct, it **should** output 1.

Below is what I am doing currently:

```
static void checking(double n, ref double max, ref double smax)
{
    if (n > max)
    {
        smax = max;
        max = n;
    }
    else if (n > smax)
    {
        smax = n;
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double n = 1, max = -99999999, smax = -99999999, ISsmaxrepeating = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (n != 0 && i < 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input number");
        n = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (n % 1 == 0)
        {
            checking(n, ref max, ref smax);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            smax =0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (smax != 0) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("secondmax is {0}", smax);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And here are some **test cases:**

*example 1.:*

> **input:** 10 5 -4 8 5 0
>
> **output:** 8

*example 2.:*

> **input:** 5 5 5 5 0
>
> **output:** "error"

*example 3.:*

> **input:** 1 0
>
> **output:** "error"

*example 4.:*

> **input:** 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>
> **output:** 9

Comment: *without using array...* is bit confusing. What does it have to do with array? did you mean you can't store the list of numbers anywhere?

Comment: i ment with using only variables :)

Comment: Well then you will have to make it a recursive function call...

Comment: n % 1 == 0 is trivially true for integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ignore a number if you already have it:

```
...
while (n != 0 && i < 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input number");
    n = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (n % 1 == 0)
    {
        if(n != max && n != smax)
            checking(n, ref max, ref smax);

        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        smax =0;
        break;
    }
}
...
```

By the way, I am not convinced of the way you try to handle error cases.

Comment: this // if(n != max && n != smax) // is not working :)      i have if(n % 1 == 0) for checking if is number inputed by user not decimal :)

Comment: I meant as an additional condition. Not as a replacement.

Comment: I added some more context. Maybe, it gets clearer now.

Comment: now i understand how it works :D but guys I have 1 more problem... I dont know how to handle negative numbers should i just assign to max and smax smallest double value ?

Comment: Yes, that's `Double.NegativeInfinity`.

Comment: There is only 1 problem now: when I input 5,5,5,0 it should output error but it outputs Double.MinValue

Comment: Well, obviously you should not check for 0 any more: `if (smax != Double.MinValue) ...`

Answer (score 1):

Final program :)

```
static void checking(double n, ref double max, ref double smax)
    {
        if (n > max)
        {
            smax = max;
            max = n;
        }
        else if (n > smax)
        {
            smax = n;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double n = 1, max = Double.MinValue, smax = Double.MinValue;
        int i = 0, stopInput = 0;

        while (n != 0 && i < 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input number");
            n = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (n % 1 == 0 && n !=0) //this (n % 1 == 0) part checks if number is not decimal
            {
                if (n != max && n != smax)
                    checking(n, ref max, ref smax);
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        if (stopInput ==1 && smax != Double.MinValue) 
        {

            Console.WriteLine("secondmax is {0}", smax);

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the full code of the checking method:

```
private static void checking(double n, ref double max, ref double smax)
    {
        if (n > max)
        {
            smax = max;
            max = n;
        }
        // Extra check added here
        else if (n > smax && n != max)
        {
            smax = n;
        }
    }
```

I tested this with a few inputs (5, 5, 5, 0 and 1, 2, 1, 0) and it behaves as expected ("1" in the second case, "error" in the first).

Also, your `n % 1 == 0` check is a very strange thing to do; I would recommend either altering that or adding a comment explaining why you're doing it for readers' benefit.